# How to get selected value from xml?

Tags: java, xml

Maybe somebody can help me with this question.
I try to reed XML file with this code:

```
    protected void parseAndReadXML (String xmlFile){
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setValidating(false);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = db.parse(xmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("films");

                System.out.println("Information of comedy films");

                for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength();i++){

                    Node firstNode = nList.item(i);

                    if(firstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                        Element firstElem = (Element) firstNode;

                        NodeList fstNmElmntLst = firstElem.getElementsByTagName("name");

                          Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);

                          NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();

                          System.out.println("Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                          NodeList secNmElmntLst = firstElem.getElementsByTagName("actor");

                          Element secNmElmnt = (Element) secNmElmntLst.item(0);

                          NodeList secNm = secNmElmnt.getChildNodes();

                          System.out.println("Actor Name : " + ((Node) secNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                          NodeList therNmElmntLst = firstElem.getElementsByTagName("year");

                          Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) therNmElmntLst.item(0);

                          NodeList therNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();

                          System.out.println("Year : " + ((Node) therNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {       
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

This is the XML that i work with it

```
<CinemaCity>
  <genre>
    <comedy>
        <films>
            <name>A</name>
            <actor>CBrus</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>B</name>
            <actor>CBrus2</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>C</name>
            <actor>CBrus3</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>D</name>
            <actor>CBrus4</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
    </comedy>
    <horror>
        <films>
            <name>A</name>
            <actor>HBrus</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>B</name>
            <actor>HBrus2</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>C</name>
            <actor>HBrus3</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
        <films>
            <name>D</name>
            <actor>HBrus4</actor>
            <year>111</year>
        </films>
     </horror>
   </genre>
</CinemaCity>
```

I need to print only Comedy film.
After running this code i get all films in all genre.
What wrong i did?

Comment: Your nodelist contains all <films>, you probably want to modify it to <comedy> (in line : NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("films");)

Comment: @User404 make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use xpath to search XML documents.  Not only is it the most concise api, it is also the most efficient when traversing the XML doc.

Here is the piece of code you need:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

Document doc = db.parse(xmlFile);

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nList = (NodeList)xPath.compile("/CinemaCity/genre/comedy/films")
        .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println("Information of comedy films");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("films");
```

You select all films. If you modify the films to comedy, your nodelist will contain all the films under comedy.

Comment: "If you modify the films to comedy, your nodelist will contain all the films under comedy." Not quite. The nodelist would just contain the comedy node itself. You'd probably need to change that line to `doc.getElementsByTagName("films").item(0).getChildNodes()`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("films");
```

To:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName( "comedy" ).item( 0 ).getChildNodes();
```

In this case you select a first comedy films node and then all child nodes for it.